# RAW, are undead and constructs affected by disease?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, immunities, disease, constructs

I can't find any information on constructs or undead having a disease immunity. The Contagion spell gives diseases. Could someone, RAW, cast Contagion on a stone golem, for example, and give it fleshrot, despite it not having any flesh to rot?

Comment: Im sure you know this, but: I closed this question because I believe it has effectively been asked before. If the linked question does *not* answer your question, please leave a comment or edit your post explaining why. Your question can always be reopened.